# How to check recursive binomial coefficient algorithm for overflow

Tags: c, recursion, integer-overflow

I suppose I could check the (n,k) args, which would be fine for the specific code below, which indeed needs some better overflow check. But I was also wondering if there's a more general approach to address possible overflows when implementing a recursive algorithm. Here's the specific example that (a)I need to solve, and (b)got me wondering about the more general question...

```
#include <limits.h>
/*===========================================================================
 * Function:    binky ( n, k )
 * Purpose:     Binomial coefficient n!/k!(n-k)!
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Arguments:   n (I)           int n >= 0
 *              k (I)           int k = 0,...,n
 * Returns:     (int)           Binomial coefficient n!/k!(n-k)!,
 *                              or -1 if the result would likely overflow,
 *                              or -1 if argument error.
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Notes:     o uses the recursive relation (n k) = (n-1 k-1) + (n-1 k)
 *======================================================================== */
/* --- entry point --- */
int binky ( int n, int k ) {
  /* --- allocations and declarations --- */
  int   this_binky= (-1),               /* init for error */
        binky_max = INT_MAX/2;          /* assert binky <= binky_max */
  /* --- check args for "convergence" --- */
  if ( n<k || k<0 ) return ( -1 );      /* argument error */
  if ( n==k                             /* default=1 if n == k */
  ||   n<1 || k<1 ) return (  1 );      /* default=1 if n or k == 0 */
  /* --- recurse (in case one curse isn't enough) --- */
  this_binky = binky(n-1,k-1) + binky(n-1,k);
  if ( this_binky > binky_max ) this_binky = (-1); /* overflow check??? */
  return ( this_binky );
  } /* --- end-of-function binky() --- */
```

So you can see my naive and non-working overflow (non-)check. What's a working alternative?

**E d i t
-----------------**
From @AkashPagar's third comment below, I'm inferring he's not familiar enough with recursion to immediately grasp the problem, which I mistakenly thought was self-evident. So, for example, if you call binky(100,50), then somewhere maybe halfway down the recursion depth, binky will detect that this_binky>binky_max guard, and return -1. But that -1 just goes one level up. And then no error is detected at that one-up level, whereby a spurious result just gets passed back to the next higher-up level, etc. So what we really want is -1 passed to the original caller, which this naive check totally fails to do.

**E d i t # 2
-----------------------**
Okay, I guess one solution would be to test each branch of the recursion separately, modifying the recurse step above as follows...

```
  /* --- recurse (in case one curse isn't enough) --- */
  int binky_left  = binky(n-1,k-1),
      binky_right = binky(n-1,k);
  return ( binky_left>binky_max || binky_right>binky_max ||
           binky_left<1         || binky_right<1 ?
           -1 : binky_left + binky_right );
  } /* --- end-of-function binky() --- */
```

Comment: specify problem explicitly.

Comment: do you want to handle integer overflow in C?

Comment: @AkashPagar The question already says, _"Here's the specific example that (a)I need to solve"_, followed by the C code which compiles and works (gives the right answers for n,k args such that (n k) is less than INT_MAX). How much more do you want me to _"specify problem explicitly"_? And, yeah, handle in C, like the example is, and like the tag says.

Comment: If binomial computation exceeds the INT_MAX then what will be output?? will it become -1 or the value at which it exceeds INT_MAX while computation?

Comment: @AkashPagar see Edit to question.